# php time 'off' by 8 hours and 14 minutes

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I have a time / date problem. I'm trying to compare the current date and time the the date / time at the beginning of the day (midnight). 
The current time is:

```
echo date('d M, Y H:i:s e')."<br>";
```

This returns, as expected: "07 Oct, 2014 12:51:25 America/Los_Angeles"

Then to get the time at midnight at the start of today, I have:

```
echo date('d M, Y H:i:s e',strtotime(date('D, d M, Y')))."<br>";
```

which returns this: "07 Oct, 2014 20:14:00 America/Los_Angeles"

The 10 (8pm) is odd since shouldn't UTC be 08:00 not 20:00? and the 14 minutes?

Can anyone help me understand what is going one here? What am I missing?

Many thanks

Comment: That line of code is **UGLY** and **POINTLESS**. Why do you take todays's date, format it into a non-standard format, then transform it into a Unix timestamp, then try to convert it to yet another format?

Comment: Simply `echo date('d M, Y 00:00:00 e');` works.

Answer (score 1):

You are sending a confusing date string into the `strtotime` function.

If you try this:

```
echo date('d M, Y H:i:s e').'<br>';
echo date('d M, Y H:i:s e',strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')))."<br>";
```

You will get a consistent result as `Y-m-d H:i:s` is a much better format for `strtotime` to work with.

From the [docs on `strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

> The function expects to be given a string containing an English date format and **will try to parse that format into a Unix timestamp** (the number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC), relative to the timestamp given in now, or the current time if now is not supplied.

and

> To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD) dates or DateTime::createFromFormat() when possible

To get the time you're looking for at midnight (I wouldn't suggest this approach):

```
echo date('d M, Y H:i:s e',strtotime(date('Y-m-d')))."<br>";
```

You can easily just output a "timeless" date and insert a static `00:00:00` directly inside the date function:

```
echo date('d M, Y 00:00:00 e')."<br>";
```

But I like using [`DateTime` objects](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php):

```
$midnight = new DateTime('today');
echo $midnight->format('d M, Y H:i:s e').'<br>';
// Output from sandbox is: 07 Oct, 2014 00:00:00 US/Pacific<br>
```

The nice part is you can easily compare them natively without any additional manipulation:

```
$now = new DateTime('now'); // 2014-10-07 12:34:56
$midnight = new DateTime('today'); // 2014-10-07 00:00:00

var_dump($now > $midnight); // true
var_dump($now < $midnight); // false
var_dump($now === $midnight); // false
var_dump($now !== $midnight); // true
```

Comment: date('d M, Y H:i:s e',strtotime(date('Y-M-d')))."<br>"; for midnight time

Comment: @JohnConde I saw your comment before you deleted it and addressed it with my preferred method

Comment: +1 since the question is asking why the OPs code returns an unexpected time, which is addressed here with doc references.

Comment: @showdev Thanks, I've added your comment about `date('d M, Y 00:00:00 e')` to my answer as well for completeness

Answer (score 1):

`date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` gives you *current* time, not midnight. Try to use next code:

```
echo date('d M, Y H:i:s e',strtotime(date('Y-m-d 00:00:00')))."<br>";
```

"00:00:00" set time to midnight.

And you may use this simple variant:

```
echo date('d M, Y 00:00:00 e')
```